# using javascript queryselectorall instead of jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

I want to rewrite this **jQuery** in pure **JavaScript**:

```
var gallery1 = $('.gallery a');

gallery1.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('onclick');
});
```

After trying to figure it out I ended with something like this:

```
var gallery = document.querySelector('.gallery a');

gallery.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('onclick');
};
```

But it works only with the first anchor of the `ul`.

When I try to use `querySelectorAll('.gallery a')` it does nothing.

I`m new to **JavaScript**. Can someone help me to figure it out?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
    <li class="">
        <a href="img/gallery/gallery1.jpg" class="" id="anchor">
            <img src="img/gallery/gallery1.jpg" alt="image 1" class="img">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="img/gallery/gallery2.jpg" class="">
            <img src="img/gallery/gallery2.jpg" alt="image 1" class="img">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="img/gallery/gallery3.jpg" class="">
            <img src="img/gallery/gallery3.jpg" alt="image 1" class="img">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="img/gallery/gallery4.jpg" class="">
            <img src="img/gallery/gallery4.jpg" alt="image 1" class="img">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="img/gallery/gallery5.jpg" class="">
            <img src="img/gallery/gallery5.jpg" alt="image 1" class="img">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the array-like nodelist from `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var gallery = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery a');

gallery.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onclick = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('onclick');
  };
});
```